# Complicated SQL selection Statement in Big Query

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I have a table with 4 columns, latLng, dataTime, stage and index . I want to query the table in a way that the result would be

- Within a time range
- no duplicate of latlng, returning the most recent latLng which is of the nature "lat,lng" eg. 23.123,1344
- ordered by stage and then index.
- within the specified radius of the latLng.

Don't know how to achieve this in sql statement yet, but [big query](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com) is making matter worse coz statement like distinct is not supported. My options so far just to achieve the first 2 on the list has really being challenging.

```
SELECT * FROM data.example
WHERE timeCollected IN
(SELECT max(timeCollected) FROM data.example GROUP BY latlng) order by col1,col2,col3
```

In what way can i achive this, Thanks.

**Update**

with this statement, i am able to query data within a range and specified time. but still unable to select duplicate rows with most recent latlng (if more than one row has same latlng, it should pick the most recent).

```
SELECT *, ( 3959  * acos( cos( radians(12.18663) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long) - radians(6.65604) ) + sin( radians(12.18663) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM data.example WHERE TIMESTAMP(timeCollected) <= DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), 60, 'minute') HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY 
distance ASC
```

Comment: Can you share the open data dataset? I'll write the query for you if you do

Comment: you can find many test samples on https://bigquery.cloud.google.com

Comment: @FelipeHoffa how do i share the dataset

Comment: On the bq web ui, click the drop down right next to the dataset name, share, add "everyone authenticated"

Comment: Just did. You can check now

Comment: Cool! Now you need to share your projectid:dataset.tablename here so I can find it (or someone else, if they can get to write the query sooner than me)

Answer (score 0):

was able to run do it after some long hours. Don't know how efficient this statement might be but here it is:

```
    SELECT latlng, max(TIMESTAMP(timeCollected)) as timeCollected,first(sessionKey) as session,first(stage) as stage,first(index) as index,
( 3959 *  acos( cos( radians(9.0071) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long) - radians(7.56511) ) + sin( radians(9.0071) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM opendata.openQueryData WHERE TIMESTAMP(timeCollected) > DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), -60, 'minute') GROUP BY latlng,distance HAVING distance < 25
order by  session,stage,index ASC
```